# SQL Server Migration Assisstant (SSMA) doesn't see my schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-migration-assi

I can connect to my 12c Oracle database using Oracle's Sql Developer and see my schema, but when I connect via SSMA I can't.  I see a bunch of other schemas in SSMA, which I assume came with Oracle because I've only created two users on the box and I don't see either of them in SSMA.  I'm connecting using the *System* account, so I don't think it would be a permissions issue.  As you might be able to tell I don't know much about Oracle.  Where could my schema be hiding?

Comment: Is your schema in oracle is empty?

Comment: Oh, good question.  No, got a ton of tables and data in there.

Comment: `Tools -> Project Settings ->Loading System Objects` is your schema visible here?